# A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider. (Error 0x800b0109)

Tags: ssl-certificate

I'm trying to patch a windows server 2016 manually (Cumulative update and etc)...

Got this error:

A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider. (Error 0x800b0109.

I also check and compared all the certificates to a working one and it they have similar certificate. Not sure what else to do.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.